# C# Excel Add in : Make worksheet read only but editable through code

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop

I have created an Excel add-in in C#, In my add-in I have a form that retrieves data from web service and writes it to excel, I want  to make the excel sheet read only, but I also want to edit it from behind the code.

**What i want to do:**

Basically I want to block user from accessing the worksheet, he can only make changes through the form that I have created.

I tried:

**1**- To add cell validation to forbid any changes to the cell but it still allows other operations on sheet such as delete rows columns etc.

**2**- To protect worksheet using a password like this.

```
var activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet);
activeWorksheet.Protect("password");
```

But the above will not let me edit the worksheet through code, I have to unlock the worksheet whenever i want to make changes ie.

```
activeWorksheet.Unprotect("password");
// Do some changes.
activeWorksheet.Protect("password");
```

This way worksheet will stay unprotected while my Edit code is running (it may consume some time as there may be thousands or more records in sheet).

I can think of one way is to unlock invidual cells to edit them and lock them again, I tried the below code but its not working:

```
var cellToEdit = activeWorksheet.Range["A2"];
activeWorksheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add("A1",cellToEdit , "password");
cellToEdit.value = "changed cell";
```

Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested writing a code than runs longer say 3 to 4 seconds and it seems that by default, excel doesnt allow worksheet to be edited while the code in still running.

Answer (score 0):

> This way worksheet will stay unprotected while my Edit code is running (it may consume some time as there may be thousands or more records in sheet).

If you display a modal form (e.g., progress dialog) during the update processing, the user will not be able to make edits while the sheet is unprotected.

Comment: good idea, but i don't know how to show a progress dialog in excel, is this possible? if yes can you please point me to any resource?